# How to run 3 scriptella files one after other from java program?

Tags: java, scriptella

I have 3 scriptella scripts I want to run from the java program one after another. It is very important, because each xml script uses the results of the previous one. How can I accomplish that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add code snippets instead of describing it ?

Comment: I can, but it is no reason for that. All it matters that each etl.xml should be ran after the previous is finished working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scriptella Tutorial](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/tutorial.html#Executing+ETL+Files+from+Java) provides an example of calling ETL files from Java. You can simply add 3 lines sequentially:

```
EtlExecutor.newExecutor(new File("etl1.xml")).execute(); 
EtlExecutor.newExecutor(new File("etl2.xml")).execute(); 
EtlExecutor.newExecutor(new File("etl3.xml")).execute();
```

These methods are synchronous, hence the etl files will run one after another.